# libgdx BitmapFont display text on small scale

Tags: libgdx

I have `OrthographicCamera` with viewport `16x9`.
Lets say for example that devices real resolution is `1024x576`

```
this.cam = new OrthographicCamera(16, 9);
```

I create BitmapFont like this:

```
FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter params = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
params.fontFileName = "font.ttf";
params.fontParameters.size = 19;
```

Font size in pixels iz 19. That is calculated like this: `screenHeight(576)/cameraViewportHeight(9)*0.3`
0.3 is how big font should be in camera units

Since font is rendered on camera mentioned above, we have to scale font to our camera size:

```
font.getData().setScale(0.015f);// 0.3/19
```

I dont know if my math is ok, but this works fine on libgdx version 1.7.1. If i update to any higher version (currently 1.9.2, but i also tried 1.7.2), font just dont display
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: wouldn't you just set the size to .3 and not have to do any further scaling?

Comment: Size is int and its in pixels, so no

Comment: I highly recommend using a screen sized camera for text and UI. Then you can easily keep it looking crisp and drawn with nearest filtering. Use arbitrary units and camera size only for your game world.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I cant do that because this is in game text, its position should be always the same on game camera....

Comment: You could project the game world text position to screen coordinates using gameCam.project(), but I guess you're out of luck if you need to depth sort the text among other objects in your game. I'm not sure about your issue, but have you called setUseIntegerPositions(false) on your text?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thats it. `setUseIntegerPositions`. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Tenfour04 you really should write an answer. But it's long time ago, so I'd like to post an answer, and delete it when you post yours, to make the solution more discoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Call `setUseIntegerPositions(false)` on your font object. This solves all the issues for me.

This is given by @Tenfour04.